# problema com método onPreExecute do AsyncTask - Android Studio

Tags: android, asynctask, progress-bar

Eu tenho essa activity que exibe a pontuação do usuário do meu aplicativo. Porém, quando esta activity é chamada, o que deveria ocorrer é um `ProgressDialog` sendo exibido com a mensagem "Buscando Pizza" (de acordo com o `onPreExecute`) e quando o gráfico estiver montado (com as informações recuperadas e tals), o progress dialog deveria sumir e o usuário deveria ver o gráfico.

```
public class AtualizarPie extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Buscando Pizza...");
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Object... params) {
        userDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                Log.v("mapString", map+"");

                pontuacaoObjeto = map.get("pontuacaoObjeto");
                pontuacaoCor = map.get("pontuacaoCor");
                pontuacaoNumero = map.get("pontuacaoNumero");

                pontos.add(pontuacaoCor);
                pontos.add(pontuacaoNumero);
                pontos.add(pontuacaoObjeto);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return pontos;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> s) {
        entries = new ArrayList<>();
        entries.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(pontos.get(0)), "cor"));
        entries.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(pontos.get(1)), "numero"));
        entries.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(pontos.get(2)), "objeto"));

        PieDataSet dataset = new PieDataSet(entries, "pontuações");

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
            colors.add(c);

        colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

        dataset.setColors(colors);
        dataset.setValueTextSize(30);

        PieData data = new PieData(dataset);

        PieChart chart = new PieChart(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(chart);
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.setEntryLabelColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        chart.setEntryLabelTextSize(15);
        chart.setEntryLabelTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
        chart.setContentDescription("pontuações");
        chart.setCenterText("Pontuações");
        chart.setCenterTextSize(15);

        progressDialog.hide();
    }
}
```

Eu coloquei os dados do gráfico para serem recuperados no Background e no `onPostExecute` a montagem do Pie Chart em si. mas os dados do pie chart está dando nulo =\ está tendo algum problema no `doInBackground` pois ele não está sendo executado corretamente e não está recuperando os valores das variáveis:

> pontuacaoCor, pontuacaoNumero, pontuacaoObjeto

Comment: Está rápido porque o seu AsyncTask apenas seta um listener e termina, ou seja, o processamento do gráfico em si está em outra thread.

Comment: Cara, o objetivo principal do ProgressDialog não é estética, é sim justamente para que o usuário perceba que está acontecendo alguma coisa para que ele não aguarde de mão abandando.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira Fiz mudanças no meu código e atualizei o post. olha a questão novamente, por favor.

Comment: @acklay Sim! exatamente. Por padrão, o PieChart do android exibe uma mensagem em inglês quando não há nenhuma entrada de dados no gráfico. Eu queria suprir essa mensagem com um ProgressDialog que aguardará o recebimento dos dados para montar o PieChart.

Comment: Como eu disse, o seu AsyncTask inicializa um listener que vai rodar em outra thread. Não há garantias (muito provavelmente que não) que esse listener vai "ouvir" algo antes do asynctask terminar, por isso ele deve estar retornando o objeto "ponto" como null, pois ele termina antes do onDataChanged escrever algo no "ponto". Minha dúvida: Para que você precisa desse AsyncTask? Por que não setar esse listener no OnCreate da Activity onde você inicializa o AsyncTask, pegar o que está no OnPostExecute e jogar para dentro do OnDataChanged, e apagar esse AsyncTask?

Answer (score -1):

Eu acredito que você está usando um AsyncTask desnecessário, pois tudo que ele faz é inicializar um listener que não tem garantia nenhuma que vai retornar algum valor antes do AsyncTask concluir.

Por que você não tenta uma alteração: acredito que na sua Activity deve ter o comando que inicializa o seu AsyncTask, tipo assim:

```
new AtualizarPie<>().execute();
```

Apaga essa linha e coloca o código abaixo (ou coloca ele dentro de um novo método e chama esse método), depois apaga o AsyncTask:

```
progressDialog.setMessage("Buscando Pizza...");
progressDialog.show();
userDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            Log.v("mapString", map+"");

            pontuacaoObjeto = map.get("pontuacaoObjeto");
            pontuacaoCor = map.get("pontuacaoCor");
            pontuacaoNumero = map.get("pontuacaoNumero");

            pontos.add(pontuacaoCor);
            pontos.add(pontuacaoNumero);
            pontos.add(pontuacaoObjeto);

            entries = new ArrayList<>();
            entries.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(pontos.get(0)), "cor"));
            entries.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(pontos.get(1)), "numero"));
            entries.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(pontos.get(2)), "objeto"));

            PieDataSet dataset = new PieDataSet(entries, "pontuações");

            ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);

            for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);

            for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);

            for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);

            for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
                colors.add(c);

            colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

            dataset.setColors(colors);
            dataset.setValueTextSize(30);

            PieData data = new PieData(dataset);

            PieChart chart = new PieChart(getApplicationContext());
            setContentView(chart);
            chart.setData(data);
            chart.setEntryLabelColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
            chart.setEntryLabelTextSize(15);
            chart.setEntryLabelTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
            chart.setContentDescription("pontuações");
            chart.setCenterText("Pontuações");
            chart.setCenterTextSize(15);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```